# How select and implement proper wireless security mechanism?

Tags: wireless, authentication

I am having issue regarding wireless security Mechanisms.

1. WEP, WPA and WPA2
2. TKIP,EAP, LEAP, PEAP, EAP-TLS, EAP-TTLS and CCMP

How do we implement these security mechanism effectively on organizational Network?. I am having good theoretical knowledge about each point.

- But still i don't understand difference between point one and point two
- How to combine or use these technologies in real world implementation.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first list are security certifications or frameworks.  They define the overall security features.

CCMP and TKIP are encryption protocols.  In addition to a encryption algorithm, they include methods for exchanging keys.  Both are considered insecure.

LEAP, PEAP, and EAP, are, at a high level, authentication protocols - for determining that the station and access point are who they say they are.

Almost all commercial wireless systems use WPA or WPA2, which includes an encryption protocol CCMP, (or more commonly AES).  Enterprise networks also use one of the EAP methods for identifying the end station.